# How to use a scanner to scan through floating point values?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

OK, so I am using a scanner recognize if the next token in the string is a floating point value or decimal value and if not it will scan character by character until a decimal or floating number is found.

So if input is something like `12/35.6+=123.5.6` tokens should be found in this order.

> 1. '12'
> 2. '/'
> 3. '35.6'
> 4. '+'
> 5. '='
> 6. '123.5'
> 7. '.6' (interpreted as 0.6 float)

This is what I have so far.

```
Scanner interpreter = new Scanner(input);

    //Allows scanning of individual char tokens
    interpreter.useDelimiter("");

    Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*(\\.\\d+)?");

    //read through input
    while (interpreter.hasNext()) {

        //determines if next token is a float/decimal
        if (interpreter.hasNext(integerPattern)) {
            //extract number token
            String strVal = interpreter.findInLine(integerPattern);
            float value = Float.parseFloat(strVal);
            tokenList.add(new Token(11, value));

        }
        else{
            //should mean the next token is not a decimal or float
            //scan over token char by char
        }
     }
```

The problem I am running into is when I input something like 123.4.5 which should catch the first token `123.4` handle it and then catch `.5` as the next token. However, right it stands now it catches `123.4` but then as it handles the next token `if (interpreter.hasNext(integerPattern))` returns false an reads the period as an individual char.

Tokens will look like this

> 1. '123.4'
> 2. '.'
> 3. '5'

Comment: I try this one https://regex101.com/r/fK3eV1/1 Is that what you want?

Comment: your information is not clear. 123.4.5 is explicitly weird how many integers can be attached together like that e.g. `123.4.5`, `123.4.5.5` or more, how you can intepret it `0.5` or `4.5` or `5.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what's going on.

When the you use the `hasNext(Pattern)` method, the scanner looks at its **complete next token** and decides whether that complete token matches the pattern or not.

When the delimiter is empty, it means that the complete next token is a single character. You can see that if you try to use `String.split()` with an empty pattern.

So, when you enter `123.4.5`, what `hasNext()` actually sees is just the `1`. Luckily, that matches your pattern, so you get into the body of the `if`.

At this point, you are using `findInLine(pattern)`. This method disregards delimiters and tokens, and instead simply looks for a matching pattern. So it sees the whole `123.4` and gives that to you.

Now that you are left with `.5`, the next complete token is *just the `.`*! This doesn't match the pattern (your pattern says that if there is a `.` it has to be followed by at least one digit. A single dot doesn't match). Therefore, the `hasNext(integerPattern)` fails, and you get to the `else` part.

Here is a possible solution: have different patterns for the `hasNext` and for the `findInLine`:

```
    Pattern findPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*(\\.\\d+)?");
    Pattern tokenPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d|\\.(?=\\d)");
```

The `tokenPattern` has a positive look-ahead which means that it will accept a single-character token that is either:

- A digit
- A dot - provided that there are digits after it, though they are not in the match.

If you have a single char that matches these criteria you know you'll be able to match the full pattern. So your program changes to:

```
while (interpreter.hasNext()) {

    // Do we have the beginning of a number?
    if (interpreter.hasNext(tokenPattern)) {
        // Extract the full number
        String strVal = interpreter.findInLine(findPattern);
        float value = Float.parseFloat(strVal);
        tokenList.add(new Token(11, value));

    }
    else{
        // Handle single char token
    }
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This will scan in the next float.

```
Scanner interpreter = new Scanner(input);
while(interpreter.hasNextFloat()){
    tokenList.add(newToken(11, scanner.nextFloat()));
}
```

Comment: I can't use this because it causes problems with the delimiter. Scanning 123.4.5 using this will find the first token as 1.0

Comment: Are you using System.in? And are you setting the locale of the scanner?

Comment: No it is reading it from a string variable. It does this because the delimiter tells the scanner to read character by character so it looks for a float between each character which interprets 1 as 1.0

Comment: The scanner uses a default whitespace delimiter which will not find a float in 123.4.5. It must have a space somthing like 123.4 .5 for it to find the float

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is explicitly has two patterns

First: e.g. `1.0`, `1`, `1.89`

Handle by:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Second: e.g. `.987`, `.11`

Handle by:

```
\.\d+
```

Then you just put all of them into one regex by using or (`|`) which we get

```
\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oL6aV8/1)

A trick here is I just prefer pattern `\.\d+` over `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` in above expression, this is significant to your work.